# Two Positive Real Numbers $m$ and $m$ such that $m<n$ and $\sqrt{m}<\sqrt{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, radicals, fractions

This is a homework problem I came across for my discrete math class and I can't manage to figure out the answer. I know it is asking for an example where $m$ and $n$ are positive real numbers, $m$ is less than $n$, and $\sqrt{n}$ is less than or equal to $\sqrt{m}$.

> Find a counterexample to the following statement:   “If  $m$ and  $n$ are positive real numbers and  $m < n$,  then  $\sqrt{m} < \sqrt{n}$."

Comment: Assuming that $\sqrt{m}$ denotes the positive square root (as is usually the case), the statement in question is true. Are you sure you wrote down the question correctly?

Comment: Coz the square root function is strictly incresing....can we use it??

Comment: @SumitMittal: I doubt it, as the monotonocity condition is precisely the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{m-n}{\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}}<0,$$
we have no the needed counterexample.

Comment: Isn't the last inequality wrongly placed because $m\lt n$

Comment: @Sumit Mittal The starting problem was changed. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: There is no counter example because the statement is true, right?

Comment: @Kelsey Wright The statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

By squaring the second inequality (between positive numbers),

$$m<n\land\sqrt m\ge \sqrt n\implies m<n\land m\ge n\ !$$